# Android - How does up button work?

Tags: android, api, button, android-actionbar

From Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html):

> ...Android 4.1 (API level 16) or higher...performing Up navigation
>   simply requires that you declare the parent activity in the manifest
>   file and enable the Up button for the action bar.

This works fine but, when I commented meta entry for parent from manifest and `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` from activity class, I can still see up button, both in real device and emulator.

`uses-sdk`: `minSdkVersion="11"` and `targetSdkVersion="19"`

BTW, I had uninstalled app from emulator, did a clean build and tested again in both devices but, I can still see up button without going as per documentation.

Please help me understand - how does up button work even when not doing as per documentation?

Thanks!

EDIT: MANIFEST and Activity code.

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <!-- 
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
                 -->
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ACTIVITY CLASS:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message + " chil" );

        setContentView(textView);

        /*
        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        */
    }

    /*
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    /*
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

SNAPSHOT:
[image]

Comment: what happened when you click the up button?? it should work the way mentioned in the docs.

Comment: As mentioned - 'This works fine...' so, the functionality works fine - it goes to parent activity. But, the point is - without specifying entry in manifest file and code in activity, it should not display the button itself.

Comment: Which is, exactly, what I had asked... :) I wonder how is it working?

Comment: can you post your code and snap shot

Comment: Please see OP for same.

Comment: yes it works you still have `android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"`  Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower. comment this and check again

Comment: You are right! My bad, I didn't read the comment properly. Anyhow, please post the same in answer so that I cant accept it.

Comment: no problem posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested on emulator

Yes it works. You still have

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity".
```

Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower. So if you run on above 4.0 it works.

You can cross check my commenting or removing the above.